# asp.net core razor pages scaffolding error get_NullableAnnotation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to scaffold Razor pages from my dbcontext for a brand new asp.net core project in Visual Studio, i've done this before with no issues. i just got a new laptop and reloaded all my apps including Visual Studio on it. I have all my necessary packages for my project that is mirroring another successful project..  When i go to right click in VStudio on my folder to hold the scaffold CRUD pages , then select Add and select new scaffolded item, then select "Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)" , add my model class, add my data context class, then click Add it processes and start to create for about 10 secs or so,

[image]

then i get this error.

[image]

if i try from CLI

dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Phrases -dc AppDbContext -outDir Pages\v2 -udl -scripts

i get the same output error...

I can't figure out why i'm getting this error ?? when everything i'm doing is spot on to a previous project that worked fine and was able to create the scaffolded CRUD pages.

Comment: Please post your codes of  `Phrases`  model.

Answer (score 0):

was due to a few package warnings , i had no nuget package errors, but just warnings of NU1608 "detected package version outside of dependency contstraint.." about 4 of those. so make sure you have a clean building project :) no warnings either.. after i cleaned those up i was able to scaffold fine.